# Is it possible for the Guest user to lose "Everyone" membership?

Tags: windows-server-2003, access-control-list

It seems that the "Guest" user under certain circumstances is logged in without the membership in the "Everyone" Built-in group on Windows Server 2003. I would like to know in more detail why and when this might be the case.

Background: a printer queue has been set up on a Server 2003 machine which has been configured for Guest access. The printer queue has an Everyone:Print ACE. In general, the Guest access seems to be working and users (any users) are able to print through the queue.

Periodically (and typically only for a limited timeframe) users connecting to the queue as Guest receive an "Access denied" error. Auditing has been enabled for the specific printing queue. The security log shows that the users' logins are successful (and the network traces show successful connections to IPC$) but the subsequent printer access is logged as an "Audit failure":

```
Object Open:
    Object Server:  Spooler
    Object Type:    Printer
    Object Name:    MultiCa_Print
    Handle ID:  10201568
    Operation ID:   -
    Process ID: -
    Image File Name:    928
    Primary User Name:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\spoolsv.exe
    Primary Domain: SERVER1$
    Primary Logon ID:   DRUCKABRECHNUNG
    Client User Name:   (0x0,0x3E7)
    Client Domain:  Gast
    Client Logon ID:    SERVER1
    Accesses:   (0x1,0x6E468485)
    Privileges: DELETE
            READ_CONTROL
            WRITE_DAC
            WRITE_OWNER
            Full Control
            Print

    Restricted Sid Count:   -
    Access Mask:    0
```

<strike>The membership in the `DRUCKABRECHNUNG` domain (apparently once a Samba NT4-style domain) seems to be defunct as the domain name cannot be resolved for a list of DCs, although I would need to do some more research on that to be able to make a definite statement.</strike> The membership in the domain is still somewhat of a mystery, all communication between the print server and the DC is going back and forth is what seems like a never-ending cycle of serial NetrLogonSamLogon requests and responses (request -> 110 ms -> response -> request -> 110 ms -> response)

I strongly suspect the domain membership to be at least a trigger, if not the cause. What I am interested in is a plausible explanation of why authorizations for the printer queue would be denied given the facts that

- a) authentications seem to work as expected and
- b) the "Everyone" group should cover, well, everyone, including Guest, at all times.

Answer (score 2):

When we had a similar problem a while back, (people being denied access to a print queue that `Everyone` had access to) and opened up a Microsoft support case, we [eventually] ended up at [it being caused by the `Everyone` group not including `Anonymous` in Server 2003 and XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278259).

I forget precisely what the failure was in our particular case that caused some of our users to sometimes not be properly authenticated, but whatever it was, authentication was breaking somewhere, causing the users to be treated as unathenticated users (`Anonymous`), and having their access denied on that basis.

The fact that you have a defunct domain there, which presumably can't authenticate the users, makes me think the same thing's happening to you.  They can't be authenticated, so they're being treated as unathenticated users (`Anonymous`), and being denied access on that basis.

Comment: I stumbled upon this KB article before. What's giving me headache is that the behavior is intermittent. The network traffic for the logon sequences looks nearly identical in all cases.  The security audit logs are showing me successful "Guest" authentications all over, just with the authorization breaking afterwards for an yet unknown reason. But thanks for the pointer, I am going to see what I can make of that.

Comment: @syneticon-dj Yeah, check if you can fix it by adding `Anonymous` to the ACL (at least temporarily, for troubleshooting purposes), and either way, you're a little closer to your answer.

Comment: I tried. The ACL had the `Guest` and `ANONYMOUS-LOGON` explicitly added with the permission to "Print". It does not seem to change the behavior.